# Where can an Orbital Weapons Platform be purchased?

Tags: x3-terran-conflict

I've searched much of the galaxy, probably more than 100 sectors, but I haven't found any shipyards producing orbital weapons platforms.

I would love to get one of these to upgrade the defenses around my factories and to hold spare weapons and drones.

Can a player purchase or build a small, medium, or large orbital weapons platform?

Or are orbital weapons platforms only for the AI-controlled Core Sectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick look at the Egosoft forums turns up [a](http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=226074) [few](http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=225968) [posts](http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=256341) that indicate that it is not possible for the player to control an Orbital Weapons Platform - they cannot be purchased or captured.

*However*, there are also posts on the forum that indicate that mods or scripts can be used to add this functionality to the game, but I don't currently have the game available to test any of them and I'm not going to recommend any of them blind - but have a look around on the forum if that's something you're interested in trying.